# Search in opposite Direction using RegEx

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following string

```
{"$deletedFields":["day"],"month":8,"year":2003,"$type":"com.linkedin.common.Date","$id":"urn:li:fs_position:(ACoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,164599768),timePeriod,startDate"},
```

What i want is search in the oposite direction using the `key` to get the month and year.

```
key = 'ACoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,164599768'
```

Actually I'm fetching and grabbing a data from a file so they key is my only hope to distinguish each data.

I've done forward regular expression but i want to seach in the opposite direction.
Lets say

```
re.findall(r''+key+'.*?),\$deletedFields', page_html)
```

Like if it has some negation or opposition so it grabs the data till the $deletedFields

I don't want to do it using `reversed` string this will alter the whole file.

Required Output

Year:2003,month:8

Comment: Is that a string or a dictionary?

Comment: It is a string actually its looking like a dict because I've extracted it from a file. Already tried json parsing it won't work the data is not organized.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _reversed_ ? If you want to match something before something, reverse has nothing to do with it.

Comment: A simple `"month":(\d{1,2}),"year":(\d{4}).*?` + key should do it. The info is in the capture groups.

Comment: The problem is some keys have month some have just year and some have day also.
so it won't be a general expression there tons of keys which have different order so i just want to search in opposite direction till the $deletedfield then i can easily grab month and year.
and by revered i mean `''.join(reversed(string))` if i do reverse searching even if i get the reversed string i can reverse again.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
`keys which have different order so i just want to search in opposite direction till the $deletedfield`
After re-reading your question, it appears like you don't know where the
beginning of record is.

If for example, you have a general start with a definite end, it does no
good to specifiy a common record start then match anything up until the
key, this will get from the first start all the way to the key, possibly
grabbing other keys in the process.

But, you can still search forward by resetting the start each time you encounter
a new one.

This uses out-of-order and optional date parts. It also captures the key
incase it is needed.

Another feature is that you can include and get *all keys and dates* into a   record array simply by adding all the keys within an alternation.

So, the regex model is `$deletedfield` + `date parts` + `any of these keys`.
And insuring we do not pass a record boundary at the same time.

```
(?s)"\$deletedFields":(?:"day":(?P<day>\d+),|"month":(?P<month>\d+),|"year":(?P<year>\d+),|(?!"\$deletedFields":).)*?(?P<key>ACoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,164599768|BCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,264599768|CCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,364599768|DCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,464599768)
```

Expanded

```
 (?s)                          # Dot-All modifier

 "\$deletedFields":            # Beginning of record
 (?:
      "day":
      (?P<day> \d+ )                # (1), day
      ,
   |                              # or,
      "month":
      (?P<month> \d+ )              # (2), month
      ,
   |                              # or,
      "year": 
      (?P<year> \d+ )               # (3), year
      , 
   |                              # or,
      (?! "\$deletedFields": )      # any character, but not the beginning of record
      .     
 )*?

 (?P<key>                      # (4 start), Keys to find
      ACoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,164599768
   |  BCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,264599768
   |  CCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,364599768
   |  DCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,464599768
 )                             # (4 end)
```

Python
http://rextester.com/XXH80293

```
import re

str = (
  r'{"$deletedFields":"month":2,"year":2003,"$type":"com.linkedin.common.Date","$id":"urn:li:fs_position:(ACoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,164599768),timePeriod,startDate"},' + "\n"
  r'{"$deletedFields":"month":12,"year":2001,"$type":"com.linkedin.common.Date","$id":"urn:li:fs_position:(DCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,464599768),timePeriod,startDate"},' + "\n"
  r'{"$deletedFields":"month":6,"year":2012,"$type":"com.linkedin.common.Date","$id":"urn:li:fs_position:(BCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,264599768),timePeriod,startDate"},' + "\n"
  r'{"$deletedFields":"day":30,"month":8,"year":2009,"$type":"com.linkedin.common.Date","$id":"urn:li:fs_position:(CCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,364599768),timePeriod,startDate"},' + "\n"
)
keys = ['ACoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,164599768',
        'BCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,264599768',
        'CCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,364599768',
        'DCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,464599768']

rx_keys = '(' + '|'.join( keys ) + ')'

Rx = r'(?s)"\$deletedFields":(?:"day":(?P<day>\d+),|"month":(?P<month>\d+),|"year":(?P<year>\d+),|(?!"\$deletedFields":).)*?' + rx_keys
key = 'ACoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,164599768'

print re.findall( Rx, str)
```

Output

```
[('', '2', '2003', 'ACoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,164599768'), ('', '12', '2001', 'DCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,464599768'), ('', '6', '2012', 'BCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,264599768'), ('30', '8', '2009', 'CCoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,364599768')]
```

Comment: Deleted my answer because this was so much better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a regex for this, since you know the key. (You might want to use a regex for parsing the record once you identify it, though.) You can just search for the key, then search for start- and end-of-record markers, like so:

```
one_line='''
{{"$deletedFields":["day"],"month":8,"year":2003,"$type":"com.linkedin.common.Date","$id":"urn:li:fs_position:(ACoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,1645997{}),timePeriod,startDate"}},
'''

buncha_records = ''.join(one_line.strip().format(n) for n in range(100) if n % 2)


def find_record(key, text):
    # Could raise!
    in_record = text.index(key)

    open_brace = text.rfind('{', 0, in_record)
    close_brace = text.find('}', in_record)

    return text[open_brace:close_brace+1]

import random

try:
    n = random.randrange(100)
    random_key = "ACoAAAGiKv0BjXc8aE9HZLXpUnNcxQD4CoB1mKg,1645997{}".format(n)

    print("Searching for key:", random_key)
    record = find_record(random_key, buncha_records)

    print("Got record:")
    print(record)
except IndexError:
    print("Key '{}' was not found in records.".format(random_key))
```